# Referencia a una funcion

Tags: javascript

tengo un archivo en el cual tengo algunas funciones que luego exporto sin embargo al hacer referencia a una de esta funcion me da un error

**installRoll.js**

```
module.exports = {
    installRol(rol,message) {
        //codigo de discord js
        return message.guild.roles.create({
            data:{
                name: rol[0],
                color:rol[1]
            }
        })
    },

    installAllRoles(roles,message){
        for(rol in roles){
            role = roles[rol]
            //aqui hago referencia a la funcion de arriba
            role.forEach(r => this.installRol(r,message)) 
        }
        // console.log(roles)
    }
}
```

**uso**

```
const { installRol, installAllRoles } = require('./functions/installRol')
//como ejemplo se va asumir que ROLES.roles es:
/* esto en formato json
"MOD":[
    ["Mod","ORANGE"],
    ["Staff","GRAY"]
]
*/
installAllRoles(ROLES.roles,message)
```

sin embargo al ejecutarlo me devuelve el siguiente error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: this.installRol is not a function`, a que se debe esto?

Comment: ¿Cómo estás importando tu función?

Answer (score 0):

Cuando importas una librería esta no se agrega al contexto this. simplemente es como si tuvieras otra variable

La primera forma de llamar a tu función Es con la notación ES6 ([import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)).

```
import {installRol, installAllRoles} from './archivo.js';

...
    installRol();
...
```

La segunda forma es con [require](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/what-is-require/).

```
const actions = require('./archivo.js');

...
    actions.installRol();
...
```

Comment: edite mi pregunta, ademas mi error es en el archivo que exporto, ya que en la funcion `installAllRoles` que se exporta se hace referencia a otra funcion que esta en el mismo archivo